# Is there a way to make footnotes in modelsummary and kableExtra single spaced?

Tags: kable, kableextra, modelsummary

Is it possible to add a footnotes to a kableExtra or modelsummary table that are single-spaced?

I tried adding some latex options like in the following snippet with no luck and to add some latex functions before the footnotes themselves.

```
regression_tab <- modelsummary(reg1, fmt = 2,
                               output = "latex",
                               coef_map = cm,
                               add_rows = all_row,
                               gof_map = gm,
                               escape = F,
                               stars= c('***' = 0.01, '**' = 0.05, '*' = 0.1),
                               title = "Effect of Having Hispanic Last Name \\label{tab:lastnamereg}") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("hover", "condensed"), 
                latex_options = c("scale_down", "HOLD_position", "footnotesize", "\\setstretch{1.5}")
  ) %>%
  footnote(number = c("\\footnotesize{This table includes the estimation results of equation (\\ref{eq:1a}).}",
                      "\\footnotesize{HW is an indicator variable that is equal to 1 if a person is the child of a Hispanic-father and White-mother.}",
                      "\\footnotesize{The sample is restricted to men working full-time full-year and are waged and salaried workers.}",
                      "\\footnotesize{Column one has the regression results when controlling for hours worked, age, and fixed effects. Column two has the results after controlling for education.}",
                      "\\footnotesize{Standard errors are clustered on the state level.}"
                      ),
                footnote_as_chunk = F, title_format = c("italic"),
                escape = F, threeparttable = T
  )
```